# I Can delete a row in active sheet when particular column has no value in it (blank column) . Can I do the same for particular spreadsheet(Sheet 2)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

/ Deletes rows in the sheet when column C is empty

```
function readRows() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  
 var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
 var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
 var values = rows.getValues();

var rowsDeleted = 0;
for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
var row = values[i];
if ( row[2] == '') {
  sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
  rowsDeleted++;
}
}
};
```

I have found this function from stackoverflow which works fine for active sheet but I would like to run this function for particular spreadsheet. (Sheet name to be included in a app script).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case:

```
function remove_rows_with_empty_first_cell() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  data = data.filter(row => row[0] != '');
  sheet.clear().getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

It works fast, but if you have formulas on the sheet it's need a more complicated solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
// Deletes any row whose first column is blank
// WARNING: Assumes any valid row has data in column 1
function deleteBlankRows() {
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = doc.getSheetByName("Sheet3"); // input sheet name here
var lastRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();

for (var i = lastRow; i > 0; i--) {
var range = sheet.getRange(i,1); 
var data = range.getValue();
if (data == '') {
  sheet.deleteRow(i);
}
}
}
```

I found this script from stackoverflow. Thank you... Delete rows for particular sheet..

Comment: It's not efficient to use `getRange().getValue()` in a loop. Your script can be made more efficient. Take a look at [Use batch operations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations).